# How to add labels to a bubble chart in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, bubble-chart

Does anyone knows how to add labels to a Bubble chart in vb.net?

I can easily add the bubbles and size, but I cannot figure out how to add the labels. See detail code as example

```
    Dim xValues As Double() = {10.62, 75.54, 60.45}
    Dim yValues As Double() = {650.62, 50.54, 600.45}
    Dim size As Integer() = {10, 20, 30}
    Dim names As String() = {"a", "b", "c"}


    Chart5.Series("Series1").ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bubble
    Chart5.Series("Series1").Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues, size, names)
    Chart5.Series("Series1").MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle
```

Any help/ideas will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What labels are you talking about? Labels on the Bubbles or Axis Labels?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify on my initial question and on respond to Vishy, I was looking for Bubble labels.

I found the solution with this code

```
    For i = 0 To 2
            Chart5.Series("Series1").Points(i).Label = names(i)
    Next
```

Hope this helps someone

Regards,